# How to add images one after another in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a code to add multiple images to a DIV one after another by clicking a button. The code is below. In this case the image is getting replaced, however, I want the older image to remain and new image to be appended.

```
<html>  
    <body>  
        <form>
            <input id="inp" type='file'/>
            <div id="placehere"></div>
        </form>  
    </body>  
</html>

<script  language ="javascript">
    var elem = document.createElement("img");

    elem.setAttribute("height", "150");
    elem.setAttribute("width", "150");
    elem.setAttribute("alt", "Flower");

    function readFile() {

        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {

            var FR = new FileReader();

            FR.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
                document.getElementById("placehere").appendChild(elem);
                elem.src = e.target.result;
            });
            FR.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("inp").addEventListener("change", readFile);
</script>
```

How do I add the new image instead of replacing the existing one?

Comment: Maybe put all the code into the readFile function

Comment: You need to recreate the `elem` every time you want to append a new image

Comment: Where is your `files` array?

Answer (score 2):

```js
function readFile() {

  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    var elem = document.createElement("img");

    elem.setAttribute("height", "150");
    elem.setAttribute("width", "150");
    elem.setAttribute("alt", "Flower");
    var FR = new FileReader();

    FR.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
      document.getElementById("placehere").appendChild(elem);
      elem.src = e.target.result;


    });

    FR.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  }

}

document.getElementById("inp").addEventListener("change", readFile);
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="inp" type='file' />
  <div id="placehere">
  </div>
</form>
```

The problem with your code was you will have to create the image tag every time user uploads a file. That's why I have moved below code inside readFile() function :-

```
    var elem = document.createElement("img");

  elem.setAttribute("height", "150");
  elem.setAttribute("width", "150");
  elem.setAttribute("alt", "Flower");
```

Comment: Click the Tidy button :) and add some explaination

Answer (score 0):

The reason the image is being replaced is because on every call to `readFile` you are reusing the same img element that you created on the initial load of the script (`var elem = document.createElement("img")`).

The solution is to move the document.createElement call into the readFile function causing you to create a new image element on every every call. See below for revised code. Hope this helps!

```
function readFile() {

    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {

        var FR = new FileReader();

        FR.addEventListener("load", function(e) {

            var elem = document.createElement("img");

            elem.setAttribute("height", "150");
            elem.setAttribute("width", "150");
            elem.setAttribute("alt", "Flower");

            document.getElementById("placehere").appendChild(elem);
            elem.src = e.target.result;


        });

        FR.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }

}
document.getElementById("inp").addEventListener("change", readFile);
```